# implement guided access on iPad using Mobile Device Management

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, mdm, guided-access

I am stuck in this problem for two days now..

What I need to do is make a small `iPad` application that when the user launches, sends the iPad in `kiosk mode/guided mode`. I am required to use `MDM` for this (I am using `Meraki` for MDM  https://meraki.cisco.com/products/systems-manager ).

However, I am not able to put the little pieces of information together to make one complete solution.

I know the following things:

1. I need to make my device "`Supervised`", which I have already done using the Apple Configurator. But since then, when I connect the device to my mac, `XCode` does not show it as an option on which I can run my iOS application. Now it just shows the installed `iOS simulators`. I don't know why this has happened..!!

   1. I have created a `.mobileconfig` using `meraki`, and it is successfully installed on my `iPad.` However, whenever I try to alter the created `.mobileconfig` file in order to introduce some more `payloads`, my `iPad` refuses to install it saying that "`The profile cannot be installed due to an unknown error`". There is no use of installing the meraki-generated `.mobileconfig` file as-is because I have to include `App Lock payload` in it in order to provide guided access too. However, this payload option is not available when i am using the meraki. So in any case, I need to alter the available meraki mobileconfig file.
   2. In case i create my own `.mobileconfig` file and include the required `payloads`, How do I place it on MDM so that it can install the configuration file on the device when required

I am totally confused..!! Please help me out..!!

Comment: I am familiar with MDM but don't know what is is `kiosk mode/guided mode` and lates mdm specification don't have such words. Could you provide link where I could read about `kiosk/guided mode`?

Comment: Yeah.. http://www.imore.com/ios-6-preview-accessibility-and-guided-access

Comment: http://www.webascender.com/Blog/ID/447/How-to-Setup-Kiosk-Mode-Lock-Your-iPad-to-Just-One-App#.Uyw8iaiSxyw

Comment: Do you have ready mdm solutions? Our you just have idea that you need MDM for guided access?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many parts to your question and I'm not 100% clear on what the overall objective is, but based on what I understand here are your questions and my answers:

> > I need to make my device "Supervised", which I have already done using the Apple Configurator. But since then, when I connect the device to my mac, XCode does not show it as an option on which I can run my iOS application. Now it just shows the installed iOS simulators. I don't know why this has happened..!!

This is because when you mark a device as supervised it will get wiped out and any profiles installed will be deleted. For Xcode to be able to run an app on a device it needs to have the development profile installed. If you open Xcode->Window->Organizer after your device is connected to your Mac, it has a button named "Use for development", just press that button and XCode will be able to run your app on this device.

> > I have created a .mobileconfig using meraki, and it is successfully installed on my iPad. However, whenever I try to alter the created .mobileconfig file in order to introduce some more payloads, my iPad refuses to install it saying that "The profile cannot be installed due to an unknown error". There is no use of installing the meraki-generated .mobileconfig file as-is because I have to include App Lock payload in it in order to provide guided access too. However, this payload option is not available when i am using the meraki. So in any case, I need to alter the available meraki mobileconfig file.

If you go to the Meraki home page and navigate to MDM->Settings (make sure your profile is selected in the dropdown), make sure enforce restrictions is selected, you should see a section named "ios Supervised Restrictions". In this section there is a setting called "Single App Mode". You should enable that setting and enter app name or bundle Id there. Note, the moment this configuration (.mobileconfig) is applied the iPad will launch your app in single app mode and you will not be able to do anything else with the device other than use your app.

> > In case i create my own .mobileconfig file and include the required payloads, How do I place it on MDM so that it can install the configuration file on the device when required

You can upload your own .mobileconfig in the Meraki webpage ->MDM->Profiles->Add new->new mobile profile, in the resulting page there's a drop down for Configuration which has an option to "Upload a custom iOS/OSX configuration profile".

Comment: Thanks for your help sandeep.. will try the same and get back to you with results soon..

Comment: Hi Sandeep.. using meraki i was able to make a config file taht would lock the device in single-app mode. What i need is, the app should go in single app mode as soon as it is launched. However, in case of meraki, i need to trigger the mobile config file install by myself. Is there any way by which the file installation gets triggered by itself??

Comment: To make the device go into single app mode programmatically through your App, you can set the "Single App Mode" setting under iOS supervised restrictions in Meraki to your app. And in your app you can call [UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession), that should do it. You don't need to trigger a config profile update.